# Connect to OpenVPN server through Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, openvpn

I’m trying to create a GUI client for connecting to OpenVPN servers using electron and node but I’m struggling to figure out how to actually connect to the servers using the .ovpn files.

My question is what is the best way to connect to an OpenVPN server using node? Would it be best to Tun terminal commands like

“openvpn—config path to config”

Or is there another way applications like tunnelblick do it that might be easier or more efficient?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/resin-io/openvpn-client (although I have no experience with it whatsoever)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello I have been working with electron and ovpn on my last project, so here are a few tips.

VPNs require admin/root privilege in order to get setup, so running child_process.spawn on `openvpn --config <path>` will fail unless your electron app is being ran via sudo/admin privilege.

You can also use `electron-sudo` package, [link here](https://github.com/automation-stack/electron-sudo). This is basically a child process spawn with sudo/admin. Aka, app runs normally, but vpn command runs with sudo.

However, if your client is sketchy about giving you sudo/admin, the VPN must be ran separately prior to launching your app.

All in all its a admin/sudo thing.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Would I have to install openvpn on the clients computer? Like check if it is installed, and if it isn't install it? Do clients like tunnelblick do this?

Comment: Also it seems like running `openvpn --config <path>` hangs on `Initialization Sequence Completed`

Comment: Exactly. One way to get around this is to bundle vpn and the electron app via Visual studio. Unfortunately, I'm not well versed in Visual studio to tell you how to do this (had someone else do it). Edit: VPN connection hangs if its not run via sudo/admin.

Comment: I ran it as sudo, but for some reason it is still hanging.

Comment: If you run the same command via terminal (outside of app) and it works, then its a `child_process.exec` fault. You need to use `electron-sudo` or OS specific "Enter password for root/admin" in the `child_process.exec` command. Using `child_process.exec('sudo openvpn...') this will not work as you will not get the prompt to enter the password

Comment: For linux i can confirm that `gksudo` is the way to go. However you need a cross-OS solution, this is where `electron-sudo` comes in, either that or implementing your own sudo/admin check ( for each OS )

Comment: Oh ok, I've figured out the problem, it was routing my traffic but it was only working with my IPV4 traffic, the IPV6 wasn't changing.

Comment: For electron-sudo do I put the code in the main.js file or in the file where I actually call the openvpn command?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Check the docs/issues for more info here: https://github.com/automation-stack/electron-sudo